# Compilation error : Cannot find module 'util'

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm new programmer on angular2. I have problem when compile with angular cli.

I generate angular 2 project by angular cli.
I'm trying to use `debuglog` module on `node_modules/@types/node` by import module like this: `import {debuglog} from "util";`
I use Webstorm IDE for develop and the ide do not warning or error with my import. I checked and found `debuglog` module in path: `myproject/node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts`.

What's wrong in my code? Have any suggestion for fix it?

Project on Github: https://github.com/sinhpn92/angular2-example-types-node

Version of environments:

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.1
node: 7.7.1
os: darwin x64
@angular/common: 2.4.9
@angular/compiler: 2.4.9
@angular/core: 2.4.9
@angular/forms: 2.4.9
@angular/http: 2.4.9
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.9
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.9
@angular/router: 3.4.9
@angular/upgrade: 2.2.4
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.9
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add `systemjs.config.js` ?

Comment: Is it necessary? This project generate from angular cli and it work's fine if haven't this problem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This solved the issue for me - https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-third-party-lib

```
"types": [
  "node"
]
```

in tsconfig.app.json.

Answer (score 0):

This configuration in *tsconfig.app.json* works for me.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["node"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had to import it.

```
import util from 'util';
const message = util.format('it is %s', 'my birthday')
console.log(message)
```